# Can I pass a variable in a Meta Http Equiv Refresh?

Tags: php

I just finished this script it works well, but I am struggling to pass along the $invite variable to the register.php page. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this? I have it defined as $invite = $_POST['inviteinput'];

How do I get the users input from index.php to transfer to register.php? Thank you for your help!

HTML FORM:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    What is your Invite Code?<BR />
    <input class="textbox" name="inviteinput" type="text" />
    <BR />
    <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Verify" />
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP
include ('scripts/dbconnect.php');

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {

if (empty($_POST['inviteinput'])) {
echo '<div class="errormsgempty"><u>ERROR</u>:<br>You must enter a valid invite code to proceed!</div>';
} else {


$invite = $_POST['inviteinput'];//else assign it a variable
$invite = stripslashes($invite);
$invite = mysql_real_escape_string($invite);

$sql = "SELECT yourMemberId FROM Register WHERE yourMemberId='$invite'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=register.php">';   
} else { 
echo '<div class="errormsgbox"><u>ERROR</u>:<br>The Invite Code you entered ' . $invite . ' is NOT a valid invite code!</div>';
//($notvalidcode = "The Invite Code you entered <strong>" . $invite . "</strong> is NOT a valid invite code!");
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways
Save it in a session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['invite'] = $invite;
```

2nd is you can pass it via get

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=register.php?invite=' . $invite . '">';
```

I would recommend option 2.
Also, why are you doing `$invite = $_POST['inviteinput'];` twice?

Comment: Ok your second option worked sortof. I see it passing in the URL but it is not echoing on the register page. Ideas?

Comment: That was by mistake I removed the first $invite = $_POST['inviteinput']; - thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Ok i used "<?php echo $_GET["invite"];?>" It worked -- Thank you!!

Comment: The second solution was very helpful to me in refreshing a page before the maximum execution limit was going to be reached, see line 69 of https://gist.github.com/dexygen/3419508492db693d2e38952078f841db

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. Just add it to the URL:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" Content="0; url=register.php?var=value&othervar=hello" />
```

Note that you may be better off using:

```
header("Location: register.php?var=value&othervar=hello");
exit;
```

Comment: notice, you get the value in $_GET insted of $_POST, but otherwise its a relly good way to do it

Comment: I'm sorry but can you elaborate please? The variable I am trying to pass is called $invite. it is set by the inviteinput in the form. I tried your suggestion "URL=register.php?$invite=" However that did not work. ty for you help

Comment: The header example displays "header cannot be modified." I realize this because of the position of the script on the page so I am using the meta equiv