# Can I pass a variable in a meta http equiv refresh

Tags: php

[Can I pass a variable in a Meta Http Equiv Refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217127/can-i-pass-a-variable-in-a-meta-http-equiv-refresh)

I used the above page as reference but answer #2 does not work correctly.
My code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=mem_list.php?filename='$init'">
```

The $_GET['filename']; the mem_list.php receives the filename entry as '$init' rather than the variable it should be.  It work OK if the code is `?filename=J` but not if the code is `?filename='$init'` or `?filename=' . $init . '`.

Comment: You'll need to post your version of the code

Comment: If you want to output a PHP variable in your HTML, you need to use [PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: You need to echo `$init` in php not in plan text

Answer (score 3):

Try something more like the following, you have to tell php to echo your variable:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=mem_list.php?filename=<?php echo urlencode($init); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you have to do :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=mem_list.php?filename='<? echo $init; ?>'">
```